# Replace multiple commas in a string with a single comma using php

Tags: php, string

I have a string which has multiple commas at different places. i want to replace multiple occurances of comma in the string with a single comma.

My string is:

```
$string = "EN:25,,,BR:18,,UE:21,,,NED:24,FR:20";
```

Comment: see this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/jM9lI0/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at preg_replace. You want

```
$string = preg_replace("/,+/", ",", $string);
```

i guess.